# How to show this almost sure convergence

Tags: probability-theory

I need to show following almost sure convergence:

$X_1$, $X_2$, ..., be identically distributed non-negative random variables with $E[X_1]<\infty$. Prove that: $$\frac{X_n}{n}\to 0$$ with probability $1$.

I want to use the first Borel Cantelli lemma:
For some $\epsilon>0$:
$$A_k = \{\frac{X_k}{k}>\epsilon\}$$
$$A = \cup_{n\geq 1}\cap_{k\geq n}A_k$$
and show $P(A) = 0$. However, after apply Markov's inequality to $P(A_k)=P(\frac{X_k}{k}>\epsilon)$, I can't show $\sum_{k=1}^{\infty}P(A_k)<\infty$ ...

Thank you for your help.

Comment: https://math.stackexchange.com/q/3397637/759535 Proof of (b)

Answer (score 3):

Using the fact that $(X_k)$ are identically distributed, we have

$$ \sum_{k=1}^{\infty} \Bbb{P}(A_k)
= \sum_{k=1}^{\infty} \Bbb{P}(X_1 > k \epsilon)
= \sum_{k=1}^{\infty} \Bbb{E}[\mathbf{1}_{\{ X_1 > k \epsilon \}}]
= \Bbb{E}\bigg[ \sum_{k=1}^{\infty} \mathbf{1}_{\{ X_1 > k \epsilon \}} \bigg]. \tag{*}$$

Now let us focus on the random variable $Y := \sum_{k=1}^{\infty} \mathbf{1}_{\{ X_1 > k \epsilon \}}$. It is not hard to see that

$$ Y = \begin{cases}
k, & X_1 \in (k\epsilon, (k+1)\epsilon] \text{ for some } k = 0, 1, \cdots \\
0, & X_1 = 0
\end{cases} $$

This proves that $Y \leq \frac{1}{\epsilon}X_1$ and hence

$$ \sum_{k=1}^{\infty} \Bbb{P}(A_k) = \Bbb{E}[Y] \leq \frac{1}{\epsilon}\Bbb{E}[X_1] < \infty. $$

Now all you have to do is to apply the 1st Borel-Cantelli's lemma.

---

*Remark.* If we replace the assumption $\Bbb{E}[X_1] < \infty$ by $\Bbb{E}[X_1] = \infty$, then a similar argument shows that $\limsup_{n\to\infty} \frac{X_n}{n} = \infty$ a.s. Indeed, one has the inequality

$$ Y \geq \frac{1}{\epsilon}X_1 - 1.$$

Plugging this back to the computation $\text{(*)}$, we have

$$ \sum_{k=1}^{\infty} \Bbb{P}(A_k) = \Bbb{E}[Y] \geq \frac{1}{\epsilon}\Bbb{E}[X_1] - 1 = \infty. $$

Therefore by the 2nd Borel-Cantelli lemma, $\Bbb{P}(\frac{X_n}{n} > \epsilon \text{ i.o.}) = 1$ and thus $\limsup_{n\to\infty} \frac{X_n}{n} \geq \epsilon$. Since $\epsilon > 0$ is arbitrary, the conclusion follows by letting $\epsilon \to \infty$ (along a subsequence, if you want to be rigorous).

Answer (score 1):

**Hint:**  $\mathbb{E}(|X_1|)<\infty$ implies that $\sum_{k =1}^{\infty} \mathbb{P}(|X_1| \geq c k)<\infty$ for any $c>0$.

To prove this, use the monotone convergence theorem and the elementary inequality

$$\sum_{k=1}^{\infty} 1_{\{Y \geq k\}}(\omega) \leq Y(\omega), \qquad \omega \in \Omega$$

which holds for any non-negative random variable $Y$.